How to unset a locale variable using localectl?
Under Fedora, I've set a custom locale variable value:
localectl set-locale LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8

This modified LC_TIME indeed.
Now I'd like to get it back to unset/empty/default state.
How do I do that? Preferably, with the same tool that did the change. Both LC_TIME= and LC_TIME="" throw an error.

localectl can’t unset a locale variable directly, however it does simplify locale variable assignments, clearing LC_ variables whose value equals that of LANG. So you can clear LC_TIME by setting it to match LANG:
localectl set-locale "LC_TIME=$LANG"

If LANG isn’t set in your environment, or doesn’t match the value known to localed, you’ll need to specify it manually; run
localectl

to see the current value assigned to LANG.
systemd uses /etc/locale.conf to store its locale settings; if you can’t get localectl to work, you can edit that file instead. You‘ll need to run systemctl daemon-reload so that the changes are taken into account.

Doesn't work here on Ubuntu 20.04 if LC_TIME in /etc/default/locale was previously set to a non-existing locale  or C or POSIX (I'd say it's a bug). Also note that it assumes $LANG in your environment is currently set to the system value. Might be better to do (. /etc/default/locale && localectl...) (I don't know if /etc/default/locale is portable outside Debian-like systems).

@StéphaneChazelas that first part might have been fixed since 20.04; I can’t reproduce it on Debian 12 or Fedora 40. I’ve updated the answer to address issues with missing or mismatched $LANG, using only localectl (the underlying file is /etc/locale.conf; at least on Debian 12 /etc/default/locale is now a symlink to that).

No /etc/locale.conf on Ubuntu 20.04 (though there is a locale.conf(5) man page documenting it.
